# Accessing serializer instances in nested serializer's field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way inside of a field in a nested serializer, to access the parent serializer's instance. Specifically the instance being accessed in a list view especially where the top most serializer may have multiple instances. I would like to pass this as context, but the context is passed by the view.

When inside the field's to_representation, on a list for instance, I can access the list of instances on the parent in list view, but i'm not sure which one is the current instance being processed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question is a bit too broad so Ill give a generic answer.

Any field in DRF (including serializers since they subclass from fields) can access the parent serializer via [`self.parent`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L317). In addition you can also access the root serializer itself (the serializer being instantiated in the views) via [`self.root`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L526).

However from what I get gather in your question, you are trying to access some state from the parent serializer while in the middle of executing `to_representation`. Doing that is slippery slope since in DRF both serialization and validation are stateless processes. In other words, only root serializer can have state (store state on `self`) but that should not happen in child serializers. If you need to access state, the best way is to explicitly pass the state around between serializers. For example:

```
class ChildSerializer(Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        foo = instance.foo  # comes from parent serializer
        ...

class RootSerializer(Serializer):
    child = ChildSerializer()
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        instance.foo = 'foo'  # parent is setting state
        ...
```

You also mentioned that you are using lists. That will involve `ListSerializer`s so if you need to pass state with in there and therefore create a custom `ListSerializer`:

```
class RootListSerializer(ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        for i in instance:
            i.foo = 'foo'
        ...

class RootSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta(object):
        list_serializer_class = RootListSerializer
```

Comment: I appreciate this and found this helpful. I was able to modify the context that was passed by overriding the same to_representation function. Looking back I probably need to override the set_context instead but that'll be some refactoring later.